# Does clearing dangling objects in a git repository using gc --prune=now help in anyway?

Tags: git, garbage-collection, git-repo, git-gc

I sometimes notice a large number of dangling objects in some GIT repositories.

I have a primary-->mirror setup and i run the scheduled garbage collection only on the mirror repository everyday instead of auto.gc.

So am not worried about loosing the dangling object on the mirrors, but will removing the dangling objects help in any way like speeding up fetches, any difference in the bitmaps or object storage structure that can help in anyway ?

Comment: No. Let `git gc` clean them up to save space, but there won't be any other noticeable effects.